# How do I open a file in a Python function?

Tags: python, file, file-io

I am new at python and am trying to write a function that can open a file and choose the largest number.  I am having problems opening the file to read in the first place.  When i copy and paste the code to the shell it opens the file perfectly but inside of the function it keeps saying file not found.  The file is in the current shell directory- do I need to edit the function to redirect the shell?

```
def choose_biggest(file_0):
    with open("file_0", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(' '.join(sorted(line.split())))
    pass
```

I didn't finish yet but this is the code so far.

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post the code you have tried so we can see what's wrong with it. :)

Comment: added it in- not done yet but that's what I have so far, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change line

```
with open("file_0", "r") as f:
```

with

```
with open(file_0, "r") as f:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def choose_biggest(file_0):
    with open(file_0, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(' '.join(sorted(line.split())))
```

you don't need quote around variables

Answer (score 1):

```
def choose_biggest(file_0):
    with open(file_0, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(' '.join(sorted(line.split())))
```

The first argument in open() is a string containing the filename. The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r' will be assumed if it's omitted.